# Hide duplicate entry title

Tags: css

I am using Divi, which introduces the Post / Page title as "h1.entry-title." And, I'm also using Open Menu plugin, which also introduces their custom post type Page title as "h1.entry-title."

So, I want to hide the Open Menu h1.entry-title only, because I don't need duplicate titles.

I'm trying to target the specific Open Menu entry-title by adding he div ID in the CSS rule, but it's still hiding both and not one over the other.

Should I just add a filter to the child theme in functions.php to filter it out? I'm not a dev, so I don't write PHP. Not sure what to write to filter that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide open menu entry title by adding below css code in custom css section.

```
.openmenu > h1{ display:none }
```